# Avoid unnecessary evaluation of bound values in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Have an angular.js directive that renders as a table.  Most of the time, the table is small, so performance is not an issue.

But sometimes, the table has many rows (e.g. thousands), so rendering every row is expensive, as each bound value appears to be evaluated twice, and there are a lot of bound values.  And Angular seems to evaluate this table a lot, only to find that all of the values in it are unchanged and thus need not be rerendered, paralyzing the application needlessly.

For instance, the entire table appears to be re-revaluated when the value of `$scope.showMenu` changes on `mouseenter` / `mouseleave`.

Is there a way to tell Angular that the entire table is dependent on some other value, say, `$scope.checksum` thus if that doesn't change, then the entire table doesn't change?

```
<div class="header" ng-mouseenter="showMenu=true" ng-mouseleave="showMenu=false">
   <!-- show dropdown menu only when hovering over the header -->      
   <span ng-if="showMenu" class="menu dropdown" >  ... menu content goes here...</span>

   <h2>{{getTitle()}}</h2> 
   <p>{{description}}</p>
</div>

<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="key in rowKeys">  
      <td title="{{getRowItem(key)|pretty">{{getRowItem(key)|abbreviated}}</td>
      <td>{{getRowValue(key)|number</td>
  </tr>
enter code here
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, if you try wrapping each section in its own controller so each section has a different $scope, does that help anything?  Making the table its own directive would also create a new $scope.

Comment: That would certainly be cleaner code, separating UI from the data.  Will try that now.  I see from the list of 'Related' posts a couple on rendering large lists, so will also limit the number of rows that are rendered using `limitTo`.  Still would be nice to mark dependencies such that the dirty checking need not evaluate every bound value.

Comment: Before diving into it, I would suggest considering other performance improvements for large angularJS lists http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

Comment: This list is awesome.  This plus separating it such that mouseovers don't cause revaluations are precisely the clues I was seeking.  Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Angular 1.3 and the data in your table is not updated in other moment you must try bind once.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="key in ::rowKeys">
      <td>{{::key}}</td>
    </tr>
```

Also ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave generate more $watchers, I recommend you use CSS rules to make this effect in your menu.