# Angularjs: why is ng-repeat doing too much work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand why ng-repeat seems to be doing unnecessary work.

I have implemented a small navigation menu example to show what I mean. I have created an Angular module that contains a controller (NavCtrl), in which I:

1. populate nav menu data in $scope, and
2. create a function that returns a class based on whether or not the specified menu item is selected.  Note: this is very much like the code from [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943217), which looked like a great way to implement a general hash-based nav menu concept (please point me to a better concept if you know of one!).

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stitus/kxzWk/6/) of my example.

My question is this: why does the ng-repeat loop get executed three times? Notice the console-logging line in my Javascript method `navClass`.  When I run it in Chrome and simply load the HTML, I get the following output:

```
evaluating route: home, against page: home testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: teams testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: events testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: venues testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: settings testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: home testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: teams testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: events testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: venues testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: settings testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: home testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: teams testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: events testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: venues testmod.js:29
evaluating route: home, against page: settings testmod.js:29
```

Looks to me like the ng-repeat loop is running three times, resulting in 15 lines of output against my 5-item example menu list, even though my markup looks like it should only iterate over the items once:

```
     <div>
        <ul ng-controller="navCtrl">
           <li ng-repeat="navLink in navLinks"> <a href='#/{{navLink.Title}}' ng-class="navClass('{{navLink.Title}}')">{{navLink.LinkText}}</a> </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Explanation or constructive criticism highly appreciated!

Comment: @Eru pointed out a useful list on a similar question I asked just 30 minutes ago, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625395/avoid-unnecessary-evaluation-of-bound-values-in-angular-js.   The basic issue is that the bound values are check again to make sure they havent changed.  One approach is to limit  the list, another to unbind them.  More tweaks also possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reference...wow, I didn't realize how quickly things can get bogged down with too many watchers in angular! The 'bindonce' directive mentioned in there was also very cool.

Comment: Angular 1.3 natively supports bindonce with `{{::var}}` syntax, as well. If the data isn't going to change, you should most definitely use this strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You see the logging runs 3 times because of AngularJS 2 way data binding: $apply() and $digest(). At minimum, $digest runs twice to check if anything has changed. Dirty checking does have its cost ;(

A better way to go about this is instead of using function expression, we can use ng-class:

```
 <ul ng-controller="navCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="navLink in navLinks"> <a href='#/{{navLink.Title}}' ng-class="myVar" ng-click="myVar = 'active'">{{navLink.LinkText}} </a> 
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Hope this helps!